# Async task with Symfony 4 application

Tags: symfony, asynchronous, import

I need to import a list of members, when I want to import 1 or 2 members it goes very fast but when I want to import hundreds of them it goes slowly, and my page is loading while it is importing into the members table.
My question is how to make this importing in the background while browsing my application and receive a flash that informs me import is successful?

MemberManagerImportController.php

```
if ($uploaded) {
                    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
->>> (this line async)    $eventBus->dispatch(new ConvertMemberImportFile($import->getId()));

                    $this->addFlash('success', 'member.import_mapping_saved_successfully');

                    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_group_manager_members_import_result', [
                        'group_id' => $community->getId(),
                        'import_id' => $import->getId(),
                    ]);
                }
```

messenger.yml

```
framework:
messenger:
    default_bus: messenger.bus.event
    buses:
        default:
            middleware:
                - Arxus\NewrelicMessengerBundle\Middleware\NewRelicMiddleware
        messenger.bus.event:
            default_middleware: allow_no_handlers
            middleware:
                - 'AppBundle\MessageBus\SqsBus\Middleware\ForwardToNotificationMiddleware'
        messenger.bus.notification:
    transports:
        sqs: 'sqs-custom://'
        async: "%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)"
    routing:
        '*': sqs
        AppBundle\Member\Import\Bus\Message\ConvertMemberImportFile: async
    serializer:
        default_serializer: 'messenger.transport.symfony_serializer'
```

Comment: could you test it with this line being removed `'*': sqs` ? in case it helps - put this mapping below the `ConvertMemberImportFile `

Comment: Without 'sqs' line I can browse my application but imports no more work

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of ways to achieve it, for example:

- you can use server-side events and subscribe your client to be notified once the import is done https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-gets-real-time-push-capabilities
- simpler way is storing a record once the import is done somewhere in DB/redis and ask the backend if the operation is finished on each page load/via ajax

Comment: Actually, my problem is that I can't browse my application without the import is done. I need to browse my application while it does the imports.

Comment: oh, i missed this point, sorry, just to confirm you can configure the messenger component to work async without any problem, please read https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transports-async-queued-messages

you need to configure new transport, routing for this + run consumer which will process your messages async.

feel free to share your messenger.yaml to let me see if there are any issues with the config

Comment: I updated the question with messenger.yml content